# Protractor Locating elements by by.repeater contained within a specific div

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, protractor

In protractor, I am trying to access the buttons repeated withina specific div with id 'CreateRFQID'. These buttons are defined a directive 'gps-button-bar'. I am trying to access them by.repeater. Because these buttons also appear else where in the page, I can not just access them through
element(by.repeater('aBtn in buttonBarController.config.buttonConfigs track by $index')).

But I am trying without success to get those buttons that are sub element of the div with id 'CreateRFQID'.

Protractor code I am trying:

```
var parent = element(by.css('#CreateRFQID'));
        var first= parent.element(by.repeater('aBtn in buttonBarController.config.buttonConfigs track by $index')).row(0);
        first.getText().then(function (text) {
            console.log(text);
        });
```

Any help how to get it?
Thanks.

### View / html Fragment

```
<div ng-controller="CreateRFQController as createRFQCntrl" id="CreateRFQID" class="ng-scope">

    <gps-button-bar config="createRFQCntrl.buttonBarConfig" class="ng-isolate-scope"><div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-buttonBar">
       <label><h1 class="panel-title ng-binding">RFQ Create </h1></label>
           <span class="pull-right">

           <span ng-repeat="aBtn in buttonBarController.config.buttonConfigs track by $index" style="padding-right: 2px" class="ng-scope">
               <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs ng-binding" id="&quot;myButton&quot;+$index" ng-click="buttonBarController.clickHandler($index);" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Create" ng-show="buttonBarController.gpsShownButtons[$index]" ng-disabled="buttonBarController.gpsDisabledButtons[$index]">
                    <span class="fa fa-floppy-o"></span> Create
               </button>
           </span><!-- end ngRepeat: aBtn in buttonBarController.config.buttonConfigs track by $index -->
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in the selector, you don't do `.row` on the result of `element` but on the `by`

```
var parent = element(by.id('CreateRFQID'));
var first = parent.element(by.repeater('aBtn in buttonBarController.config.buttonConfigs track by $index').row(0));
first.getText().then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```